# Isolating encrypted and unecnrypted Windows installations and protecting the boot loader

Tags: windows, disk-encryption, spoofing, veracrypt, boot

I want to use my PC both for gaming and for stuff like keeping cryptocurrency wallets, online banking, etc. I need to install games as admin but of course I don't want them to be able to access my wallets data in any way even if they have keyloggers. Also games require full performance. The only way I see to achieve this is to have 2 Windows installations in my boot configuration:

1. Unencrypted Windows for games
2. Encrypted Windows with cryptowallets

The security issue here is that apps running in unencrypted windows can alter VC boot loader to get my password. Is there a way to prevent it? Are there any other issues?

I know about cold storage wallets, please don't suggest them.

Comment: Install Windows on an external drive (Windows 2Go), for instance. This way the game-mode Windows don't even know there's another installation. Performance won't be great, but it works.

Comment: Interesting solution. So the encrypted one can be on a portable SSD. And I should set USB as a 1st boot priority. When I need to boot the gaming Windows, I can just unplug that SSD. Unless something on the gaming Windows messes BIOS firmware, it is secure. Which I can't control, can I? @ThoriumBR

Comment: If you are worried about a sophisticated malware messing with the BIOS and the loss from the crypto wallets are larger than the cost of a low-end computer, buy another computer.

Comment: @ThoriumBR I guess cold storage wallet is cheaper than a computer

Answer (score 0):

> The security issue here is that apps running in unencrypted windows can alter VC boot loader to get my password. Is there a way to prevent it? Are there any other issues?

With Secure Boot on (any x86-64 computer built in the last 10 years) this won't/can't be happening.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/system-security/trusted-boot

Secure Boot has been hacked recently, so it's on you to keep your BIOS and your Windows installation up to date.

https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2023/03/unkillable-uefi-malware-bypassing-secure-boot-enabled-by-unpatchable-windows-flaw/

TBO I don't even like the idea of having potential malware co-existing with your secure Windows installation. If I were in this situation, I'd have two physical disk drives and switched between then when necessary.

Comment: Switching SATA or M2 disks inside PC is not that easy. Doing that with notebook every time is unreal.

Comment: For Secure Boot, it must allow VeraCrypt boot loader. If that boot loader can be added to the trusted list, what prevents another app with admin privileges to register its own malicious boot loader the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Windows nowadays has several features to protect the boot process

**Secure Boot**. PCs with UEFI firmware and a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) can be configured to load only trusted OS bootloaders.

**Trusted Boot**. Windows checks the integrity of every component of the startup process before loading it.

**Early Launch Anti-Malware (ELAM)**. ELAM tests all drivers before they load and prevents unapproved drivers from loading.

**Measured Boot**. The PC's firmware logs the boot process, and Windows can send it to a trusted server that can objectively assess the PC's health.

---

You could also consider creating a vm for your crypto wallets and run all the crypto things in that VM, and run your games directly.
You can also harden and secure that crypto vm then with some hardening benchmarks

Comment: For Secure Boot, it must allow VeraCrypt boot loader. If that boot loader can be added to the trusted list, what prevents another app with admin privileges to register its own malicious boot loader the same way? Does VeraCrypt bootloader have the same integrity self-checks?

Comment: VM inside a possibly-infected host is not secure in any way. The host can keylog virtual disk encryption passwords and access wallets data.